# how to convert buffer string to the image?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a buffered string and I want to display it as an Image in Android by setting it to an `ImageView`.

Can you please tell me how?

My logic is:

```
HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();                    
if (resEntity != null) {
    buffer = new StringBuffer("");
    buffer.append(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
byte []bt = buffer.toString().getBytes();
Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bt, 0,bt.length);
img.setImageBitmap(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
 byte []bt = buffer.toString().getBytes();
 Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bt, 0,bt.length);
```

use this

```
 Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer.getBytest or buffer.tobytes, 0,bt.length);
```

I dont know what your buffer is, but try getting bytes directly instead of converting it into String and then getting bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
byte []bt =EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bt, 0,bt.length);
img.setImageBitmap(i);